# SAP BTP Launchpad (Trial) managed HTML5 apps are not visible to catalogs and groups assignment

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform

1. Built and deployed a simple list fiori app using Business Application Studio as a 'Managed Application Router'
2. New App is visible under HTML5 Apps in the BTP cockpit
3. In BTP launchpad, new app is visible in Content Explorer and can add it to managed content.
4. Can add new app to 'Everyone' Role
5. Create a new catalog, but new app is not visible when trying to add apps to the catalog.  All other 'local' apps are and can be assigned to the catalog (or group)

Is there a configuration or setting that must be made e.g. when the app is deployed to BTP to make it possible to launch the managed router app from the central launchpad ?

Comment: Trial services have limitations

Answer (score 0):

If you're still facing this issue, make sure visualization parameters are configured for your app under Content Manager. This usually gets filled automatically when you add FLP configuration at the time of creating Fiori app from template in BAS (for example) and deploy to BTP. Only apps with visual representation are visible when you assign them to a group or a catalog.